# How to add css from node_modules to template.html in Svelte

Tags: css, import, node-modules, svelte

I have a sapperjs app that like one you get from calling `npx degit sveltejs/sapper-template my-app`. I'd like to add a font. Normal people might add a line like this to `app/template.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">
```

Network reasons make this impractical, so I want to host the font locally. In create-react-app I would simply `import 'typeface-roboto-slab'` at the top of my App.jsx or equivalent component. How can I achieve a similar effect in my sapper/svelte app?

I believe it's best to add it to `app/template.html` because anywhere else and the css would be scoped to an individual component. This seems like something that almost any app would need, but nothing about it in the docs that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite as streamlined as CRA (yet!) but you can achieve this fairly simply by copying the fonts into your `assets` folder...

```bash
npm i typeface-roboto-slab
cp -r node_modules/typeface-roboto-slab assets
```

...then adding a `<link>` in your `app/template.html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="typeface-roboto-slab/index.css">
```

In version 0.19, Sapper gained the ability to import CSS files directly, but it doesn't currently know how to deal with referenced files like `url('./files/roboto-slab-latin-100.woff2')`. That'll be supported in a future version, and then you'll be able to use fonts the same way that you can in CRA.

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm importing css styles "import 'node_modules/.../file.css'" with rollup-plugin-css-only. The style looks good but fails to resolve the path to the images. Would it be the same problem or the image files have a solution?

Comment: Is there some rollup plugin (no sapper here, just svelte) that supports importing css from an npm package, which also supports referenced files (fonts, icons, images)???