# Import css in node_modules to svelte

Tags: svelte

I want to use css framework in my svelte project, in this case it was uikit.

I had install it with `yarn add uikit`

And of course i have to import the css file, with

`@import '../node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css"`

But that's not work, wherever i'm import that

- App.svelte style
- Inside global.css
- Using  tag inside index.html

Is this not available yet?

Or am I should install that with yarn, and after that I have to copy required file to outside node_modules just like [this solution]?([How to add css from node_modules to template.html in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129277/how-to-add-css-from-node-modules-to-template-html-in-svelte))

I think this is not restriction just for uikit, instead the way we import third party css file in node_modules into svelte app

[image: error]

Answer (score 29):

I had some trouble following Marvelous Walrus's answer, so here's a more
explicit version of the same steps.

Rollup is the bundler used by svelte. (You might know webpacker as a bundler).

**Step 1: Install the rollup css plugin:**

```
npm install -D rollup-plugin-css-only
```

**Step 2: edit `rollup.config.js`**

you need to import the plugin you just installed at the beginning of  `rollup.config.js`:

```
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";
```

and farther down in the file you need to find the array of plugins, and add a new on called css.  For example I inserted it before the `svelte` plugin, which looks like this:

```
  plugins: [
    css({ output: "public/build/extra.css" }),
    svelte({ ...
```

When rollup does it's thing, it will read all the css-files imported by your components,
combine them into one, and write them to `public/build/extra.css`

**Step 3: edit `public/index.html`**

Add the link to the new css file.  For me this looked like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/extra.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/bundle.css" />
```

**Step 4: profit!**

Now you are all set to use css files from your installed npm packages.
for example I added bootstrap by

```
npm install bootstrap
```

then finding the css files I want to use (they were in /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/)
and importing them in the beginning of App.svelte:

```
<script>
  // build/extra.css is fed from css files imported here
  import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css";
```

**Open Questions**

Rollup does not seem to handle the sourcemaps that are mentioned
in bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-grid.min.css.  So when I open the
developer tools I get a warning about not being able to load the sourcemaps

Comment: Doesn't seem to be valid for svelekit

Answer (score 16):

1. Install the rollup css plugin:

`npm install -D rollup-plugin-css-only`

2. Go to rollup.config.js and configure it by adding the installed plugin to the plugin list, with the output param where the value is a css file. Later that file will be created in your public folder and the contents of the original css file will be copied into it:

`css({ output: "public/uikit.css" })`

3. Go to index.html and add the link to your file to the head section:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="uikit.css" />`

4. import the original webkit css file into the script tag of your Svelte component:

`import "../node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";`

The solution is not mine. All credits go to this guy (circa 6:00 in the video):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBQg89ak_NY

Comment: It's a good answer (which should be accepted, by the way). Maybe it worth to show the pieces of code so it will be much easier to understand. Or, at least, link to those pieces in the example repo. For example: https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-svelte-tutorial/blob/master/rollup.config.js#L6.

Comment: I'm hoping someone sees this even though I'm posting much later. I'm wondering what the point is in installing via npm instead of just copying the minified css and js files and storing them in your static folder yourself. Since you have to link them in the template.html or index.html file anyway why not just copy the raw files themselves and then you don't have to import the css in the script of your .svelte files

Comment: @Jeff I think the main reason would be for maintainability - in like 2 years when you're having to update dependencies, you might not remember to copy/paste the updated css code into "public/global.css" - if you do it this way you can simply update your dependency in `package.json` and be done.

Comment: Thanks @GavinR I hadn't thought of that part

Comment: currently this does not seems to work anymore. rollup complains about error that  i'm importing non-javascript file. Any advice?

Comment: It's work fine if the imported .css do not refenences images, in which case the images will not be found Example importing datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css returns  [08:27:47] 404 ─ 0.39ms ─ /images/sort_asc.png

Answer (score 16):

With Svelte v.3.24.0 and [svelte-preprocess](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) it is possible to import css directly in your component's style tag.

rollup.config.js:

```js
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

...
svelte({
    preprocess: autoPreprocess({
        postcss: true,
        scss: { includePaths: ['src', 'node_modules'] },
    })
}),
...
```

component:

```html
<style lang="scss" global>
    @import '../node_modules/my-package/cssfile';
    @import '../node_modules/my-package/scssfile.scss';
</style>
```

- component's style tag should contain **lang="scss"** attribute.
- and please notice that **css** file's import should be [without an extension after the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279590/6623551)

So we don't need to install any additional Rollup plugins here.

Comment: that `global` is hidden gem!

Comment: It is github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess feature. I've updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

For whoever is interested in this, I'm using this neat solution:

---

1. Install `rollup-plugin-css-only`

```sh
yard add -D rollup-plugin-css-only
```

Or

```sh
npm i -D rollup-plugin-css-only
```

---

2. Use it in your `rollup.config.js`

```js
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";

export default {
    plugins: [
        css({
            output: function (styles, styleNodes) {
                // Filter out any source map imports
                let reg = new RegExp(/^(\/*).*(.map) ?(\*\/)$/gm);
                writeFileSync("public/build/base.css", styles.replace(reg, ""))
            }
        }),
    ]
}
```

---

3. Now import it in `App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import "../node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
</script>
```

---

4. Add this to your `index.html` file

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/base.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to import a CSS file directly inside the script block.

```
// path/to/your/+page.svelte
<script>
  import 'uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css';
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me. I use Sveltekit and Vite. Other suggested solutions are overly complicated for this case.

Answer (score 1):

With Parcel as the bundler, you can put in your index.js (entry point)

```
@import 'milligram/dist/milligram.min.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with UI kit, but from the information provided, it seems to me that you should be importing (using `@import`) it inside a `scss` or `sass` file, not a css file.
Using `@import` in a css file does not get interpreted, but as you can see, just shows up in your browser as a reference to a file in `node_modules` directory, which is not available to the browser.

Assuming you're using rollup, in order to process `scss` files, you will likely need to add the `svelte-preprocess-sass` dependency for rollup to support sass (and scss).

https://github.com/ls-age/svelte-preprocess-sass

Comment: yes, i'm using rollup. But are you sure I should using sass? So in svelte, we must import css file in sass file for them to worked? Seems inconvenience

Comment: there's a way to add css files with postcss and rollup, but it seems a little less convenient https://lengstorf.com/code/learn-rollup-css/

Answer (score -1):

So if you want to use UIKit I would go look at the information on the homepage.

From [HTML markup](https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction#html-markup) section in the introduction on UIKit site:

You need to add:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
```

to the head of your html file.

So in your case you could point to your node_modules folder like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
```

in your template.

Comment: Was that what you meant with "Using tag inside index.html"?

Then I think we might need to see some code to better answer your question.

Comment: From your screenshot I see that you serve up your page, but what is your "root" or "public" folder? That path you have set for the css file is most likely wrong relative to your root.

Comment: unfortunately, [my code](https://ibb.co/wRy3FGx) is same with your answer

Comment: Most likely the software you use to serve up your code won't allow you to traverse outside the /public folder.

So I would create a /css folder inside public and copy the uikit file there. And update your markup in index.html.