# Add .js/.css files to .svelte component

Tags: svelte, swiper.js

I want to add swiper slider to svelte, my question is:

1. Its possible to add css in script tag, like this:

```html
<script> import from "styles.css" ... </script>
```

Because import to head is tricky ([Import css in node_modules to svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483209/import-css-in-node-modules-to-svelte))

2. I add `swiper.js` file to svelte, and it almost works. It works on touch (mouse), but buttons don't (`.swiper-button-next` `.swiper-button-prev`). Do exist special import .js files rules ?

Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-leavitt-ygstx?file=/App.svelte:224-243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. With rollup you can just import the css file like you will do for a `.js` module:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"; // <- just import your css
  ...
</script>
```

2. For the navigation issue it's written in the [swiper documentation](https://swiperjs.com/get-started/):

> By default Swiper exports only core version without additional modules (like Navigation, Pagination, etc.). So you need to import and configure them too:

```js
// core version + navigation, pagination modules:
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

// configure Swiper to use modules
Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

// init Swiper:
const swiper = new Swiper(...);
```

So finally, your component initialisation can be done like that:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
  import Swiper, { Navigation } from "swiper";

  Swiper.use([Navigation]);

  onMount(() => {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here's the link for the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-framework-nogcr?file=/App.svelte).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i insert your example to project (routify template - https://routify.dev/guide/installation) and get the error: [!] Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript). It disappear when i remove - import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";

Comment: it wokrs with sapper, looks like need to add some loader to rollup

Comment: Yes you will need a plugin like [rollup-plugin-css-only
](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-css-only) for example. So does it respond  your question?

Comment: Yes, you helped me a lot. Thanks, and pls add to answer the plugin, mb its help somebody :)

Comment: @vladbelozertsev Could you also please don't forget to upvote my answer ? :)